# EmberJS can not display all content if opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

If I run my application and click on an image it opens the detail page and show me all content properly. But when I copy the link and paste it on a new tab or right-click an image and open in new tab, I can't see the whole content. What do you think the problem is? This is my twiddle. Thanks

https://ember-twiddle.com/f65ee2dc539c38a104e003af289db23a?openFiles=templates.pic.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider ember-data for this requirement like lux and ateek said..
For time being i solved your problem using services.. have look at the [twidde](https://ember-twiddle.com/b9cd8b1b3418d876f88235c4aa99e268?openFiles=routes.pic.js%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs&route=%2Fnews%2FSimdi-de-GeForce-GTX-1080-Ti-sesleri).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't see services part on the tutorials, I guess I missed it. That solved my issue.

Comment: hello,@kumkanillam you helped me before with using a service but now I need to take data from JSON api and new tab thing doesn't work again. I tried to get the data from service but I couldn't. Someone said I need to use ember-data like you, I created an adapter application.js and wrote `import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
model(params){
    return $.getJSON('http://api.donanimhaber.com/api/v1/site/NewsSite?pageIndex=0&pageSize=15',params.NewsUrl);}
});` Nothing changed. What else should I do to use ember-data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't implement the model hook of the detail (`pic`) route. So it works when you do the transition with the `{{link-to}}` helper because there you pass the model down, but it doesn't work if deep-enter the detail route directly.

Comment: pic route gets the data from index.js. how should I implement it?

Comment: @hbc this is an anti pattern. Either use a service, a static import from `utils` or best a data framework like `ember-data` to handle your data.

Comment: hello again @Lux , I'm trying to use ember-data in order to get data from JSON api but new tab thing still doesnt work. I created an adapter called application.js and wrote `import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api'; export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({ model(params){ return $.getJSON('Json api URL',params.NewsUrl);} });` still nothing has changed. Also my index.js is `import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('JSON api URL');}
}); ` What else should I do to use ember-data properly?

Comment: You should use `ember-data`, so don't use `Ember.$.getJSON` but `this.store.find`.

Comment: my model is called news-list, I wrote `return this.store.findAll('news-list');` to the pic.js route and `return Ember.$.getJSON('http://api.donanimhaber.com/api/v1/site/NewsSite?pageIndex=0&pageSize=15');` to the index.js, also I changed my model to `export default DS.Store.extend({` and put `DS.` before all attr(). But now all I see is a blank page when I click a picture. If I write this.store.findAll to index chrome's devTool says : `vendor.js:42201 Error: No model was found for 'http://api.donanimhaber.com/api/v1/site/NewsSite?pageIndex=0&pageSize=15' `

Comment: `vendor.js:38640 Error while processing route: pic Ember Data Request GET /news-lists returned a 404
Payload (text/html; charset=utf-8)
Cannot GET /news-lists
 Error: Ember Data Request GET /news-lists returned a 404
Payload (text/html; charset=utf-8)
Cannot GET /news-lists` that's the error I see on the blank page.

Comment: Please, if you have new problems ask new questions if you can't solve them by your own. Maybe also check out the slack and irc.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the concept is that model hook called when we use link-to helper by passing id of object, as im using below link-to helper. and model hook get ignore if we pass full object of model, as you are passing. 
model hook also called when we directly enter url in browser. so issue is that when you enter url in browser than your model hook called and in model hook you are not returning model of pic. so you are facing issue. solution is that 
change the line `{{#link-to "pic" pic}}`  in component template in to this

```
{{#link-to "pic" pic.id}}
```

now your model hook will call each time of transition.

and defined model hook in your pic route in that way

```
 model(params) {
       this.store.findRecord('image', params.pic_id)
    }
```

and change you router like this  `this.route('pic',{path:'/news/:pic_id'})`

Comment: It didn't work.. When I do what you say, links doesn't work.

Comment: make sure that when you enter direct url in browser than model hook in pic route called and it return model or object of image Model.

Comment: get to learn basic crud in ember.js from here.
https://github.com/jkneb/ember-crud